# Country/Territory Picklists enabled and 'before update' trigger

Tags: apex, trigger

We have 'Country/Territory Picklists' enabled and there is a 'before update' trigger for Account.
When I change BillingCountry or BillingState trigger doesn't see the difference between old and new value.

```
trigger RouteLead on Lead (before insert, before update) {
    if (Trigger.isUpdate) {

          for (ID accountID : Trigger.newMap.keySet()) {
                final Contact oldAccount = oldMap.get(accountID);
                final Contact newAccount = newMap.get(accountID);

                System.debug('BillingCountry: ' + oldAccount.BillingCountry + ' - ' + newAccount.BillingCountry);
                System.debug('BillingState: ' + oldAccount.BillingState + ' - ' + newAccount.BillingState );
            }
    }

}
```

When I change US, Arizona to US, Alabama it prints

> BillingCountry: US - US
>
> BillingState: Arizona - Arizona

I tried to disable 'Country/Territory Picklists' and it started working correctly:

> BillingCountry: US - US
>
> BillingState: Arizona - Alabama

Is that know issue and there is some workaround?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found a solution
https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000187734&language=en_US&type=1

instead of BillingCountry and BillingState  I have to use BillingCountryCode and BillingStateCode